# add_cap not working with Shop Manager role

Tags: users, user-roles

I'm running WooCommerce and have added a user with the role 'Shop Manager'.

I'd like the Shop Manager to have the ability to add users.

Here's my code:

```
function shop_manager_add_users() {
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    $role->add_cap( 'add_users' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'shop_manager_add_users');
```

However, when I log in as the Shop Manager, they are still unable to add users. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use create_users capability instead of add_users capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add_users capability is only used for backward compatibility.
so we should use create_users capability instead of add_users capability.